# How can i use Gmail API to send an email as per the

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I need help on to Read Unreaden emails count / send an email to specific or group of people and search with senders id or date to find a specific email using API Only, no programming I did the action like this https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/gmailid@gmail/profile on the browser and i got the output like below

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "required",
      "message": "Login Required",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization"
    }],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

I know, i have to pass oAuth token or client id and client secreat to the url, but i dont know how can i pass that info through URL.

Also i tried in Post-Man and i could not able tocreate the oAuth token, it is asking call back and redirect url that i dno know.

Can some body give me the idea pleaseI need only API Solution, because i need to work on API stuff, i can successfully implemented the same using java. But i could not able to do this using API ( Am not using any programming to handle the API, only Browser calls and most likely Post-Man only)

Answer (score 0):

You only need the access token to do the HTTP request. In this case, the syntax to get the Gmail profile would be this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/USERID/profile?access_token=ACCES_TOKEN`

You can easily request the tokens (and do HTTP requests) in the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). You can also read more about the getProfile request of the Gmail API [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile).

**EDIT**:

To get the number of unread messages, you have to use the `q` parameter, and change your request to `messages`:

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is:unread&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: This is some what useful for me, but the problem here is with the Sending an Email, i di dnot able to get the Payload for sending an email, what are the required parameters to send and can i parameterize the To and From Eamil Address and Message Body More importently.  I need this through API only, basically i want to send To and address and Message Body dynamically,can you please let me know thew exact payload that i need to use,                                        Thanks,                                                                                                              
Gouri

Comment: how can i get total no of un read emails in my inbox with the API On;ly

Comment: I edited my question. Sending an email from a simple HTTP request is not possible, as you need to encode the content to Base64.